# SDL_Keycodes are too big for storage

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, sdl-2, signed-integer

While searching up methods of detecting multiple keys at once in SDL 2, I came across this piece of code for SDL 1.x:

```
//author: Rob Loach
// Global key buffer
bool keys[256];

while(SDL_PollEvent(&mainEvent))
{
   if(mainEvent.type == SDL_KEYDOWN)
   {
       keys[mainEvent.key.keysym.sym] = true;
   }
   else if(mainEvent.type == SDL_KEYUP)
   {
       keys[mainEvent.key.keysym.sym] = false;
   }
}
```

I tried implementing it in SDL2 and a `std::array<bool, 256>`, but I had `Segmentation fault: 11` with the up button.

That's when I looked at this: https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDLKeycodeLookup.

Most of the 'special' keys including arrow, function, symbols, and so on have decimal representations in the billions.

Even with the simple code `printf("%d\n", e.key.keysym.sym);` on, say the up button gives:

```
1073741906
Segmentation fault: 11
```

I am on a Mac, if it makes any difference with the error codes.

So, what solutions are there to this in SDL 2?

Comment: You could use a `std::map`, that way you won't run into that problem. I don't think there is much to help you in `SDL2` specifically though.

Comment: @olevegard Perfect! Would you mind writing that as an answer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First of all, `bool`s don't default to anything in `C++`, you need to initialize them. The fact that they appear to always be `true` is that they're `byte` in size. Which means they have a size between `0` and `255` inclusive. Only `0` would mean `false` so its a `255 / 256` chance of `true`.

---

As for your solution, you would simply define your `std::map` as this :

```
std::map<SDLKey, bool> keyMap;
```

An `std::map` is initially empty, so you need to check that the items actually exists when you try to look it up.

```
bool IsKeyDown(SDLKey key)
{
    // Look for element
    auto it = keyMap.find(key);

    if (it == keyMap.end())
        // No element found, which means this key hasn't been pressed
        return false;

    // 'it' is an iterator, so we use * to return its value
    return it->second; 
}
```

When you try to set an item, it will automtically get created if it doesn't exists :

```
bool SetIsKeyDown(SDLKey key, bool isDown)
{
    keyMap[key] = isDown
}
```

So the fact the `std::map` is initially empty means you don't need to fill it. You can if you want to, but it's not required like it is with an array.

Comment: Changed some things in a edit. `it` is a std::pair, with the first object containing the key and the second object containing the value, therefore, `return (*it);` will not work, `return it->second;` will work. Also, `it` will be equal to `keyMap.end();` if it is *NOT* found, therefore, the correct code is `if( it == keyMap.end();`. Thanks for a great answer though :)

Comment: @ThatPixelCherry thanks, I should learn to run my code through a compiler before I submit...

Comment: Haha no problem :)